# Sed Merge split lines between two different patterns

Tags: awk, sed

I want to merge lines between ^pattern2 and its ";.

Change this:

```
pattern2
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx";
pattern2 
"xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

to

```
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

I've used this sed command before

```
sed -i -e '/^pattern2/!b' -e :a -e 'N;/\;/!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' input_file
```

but in this case it gives this output:

```
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx"; pattern2 
"xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$ sed '/^pattern2/{
:1
/;$/b
N
s/\n/ /
t1
}' file
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx";
pattern2  "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

As a one-liner

```
sed '/^pattern2/{:1;/;$/b;N;s/\n/ /;t1;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s` shorthand:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\";\n"; FS="\\s*\n\\s*"} /^pattern2/{$1=$1} 1' file
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

Note that the above produces the expected output from the question while the current sed answers do not as their third output line would start with `pattern2<blank><blank>"xxxx` instead of `pattern2<blank>"xxxx`. It will also work even if any of the quoted strings contain a `;` at the end of a line which the sed answers would fail with, e.g. given this input (note the `;` at the end of the 5th line inside a quoted string):

```
$ cat file
pattern2
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx";
pattern2
"xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx;
yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\";\n"; FS="\\s*\n\\s*"} /^pattern2/{$1=$1} 1' file
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx; yyyy yyyyyy yy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyy";
pattern3
"xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
pattern2 "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^pattern2/{/;$/b; :a N;//!ba;y/\n/ /}' test
```

for any lines starting with `pattern2` that does not ending with an `;` start a loop which take a new line into the buffer until meet a line ending with an `;`. When this condition is meet replace all occurence of a new line with a space. Then do the default action: print.

If you're sure that **no** `;` is embeded inside the double quotes (in places of `x`) you can short `sed` to :

```
sed '/^pattern2[^;]*$/{:a N;/;$/!ba;y/\n/ /}' test
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed` turning in its extended regex mode (`-E`):

```bsh
sed -E '
  /^pattern2(.*[^;])?$/{
    N;H;z;x;D
  }
  y/\n/ /
' file
```

---